# How do you use the rugarch package to include the stable distribution

Tags: r, time-series

In R, I would like to use `rugarch` and `stabledist`/`fBasics` packages together to fit a univariate time-series object to be modeled as an ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) process with the innovation term/conditional distribution term being modeled as a stable distribution. Is there a way to to this? given that the fBasics package allows one to have a `dstable()` function, which I'm guessing would be used to optimise a maximum-likelihood function.

And as a follow up, how would one go about simulating several thousand iterations of x days forward returns assuming it follows the same process. (I'm guessing here using the function `rstable()` with the parameters estimated above.)

Any other packages that you might think would do the job better would gladly be looked at as well.

Comment: I think you might be right, but don't know how to migrate...

Comment: I just voted to close, that should make this show up for others to vote on. You can also flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `dstable` and `rstable`, but they come from package **`stabledist`**...
If you want to estimate the stable parameters, you can use

```
fBasics::stableFit(data, type="mle")
```

to give you MLE estimate, but usually takes few minutes to compute.

Faster, but little less precise is the quantile method (implicit for stableFit, i.e. dont specify the type). 
Then if you get the fit, you extract the resulting estimates from `result@fit$estiamte` and can use it in `rstable` to draw random variates..